# Defining custom Schema methods in mongoose to return a single property?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas and from each, I want to return a single property.

Here is the schema for a single document or file.

```
// @ts-check
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const docSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  approved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  docType: { type: String, required: true },
  size: { type: Number, required: true },
  bucket: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Bucket" }
});

docSchema.methods.getSize = function(cb) {
  // Return the size of document
};

const Doc = model("Document", docSchema);

export default Doc;
```

And this is the schema for a bucket of documents

```
// @ts-check
import { Mongoose, Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const bucketSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true },
  projectId: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
  contractorId: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
  Docs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Document" }]
});

bucketSchema.methods.getSize = function(cb) {
  // return the size of all documents that belong to a single bucket
  // How do I traverse over the Docs array and use Doc.getSize()???
};

const Bucket = model("Bucket", bucketSchema);

export default Bucket;
```

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have to query the database each time I need to get the size of the bucket and then traverse over the results and add the size of each document. I want to make it simple so that basically I call `Bucket.getSize()` and it returns me the size of the bucket so I can restrict the users from uploading files when they've exceeded a certain limit.
Any help would be appreciated.